# fish tab completion based on file extension

Tags: fish

I have a command `foo` that can only run `*.bar` files. I would like to implement tab completion for `foo` such that only `*.bar` files are listed as options. In bash, this would look like:

```bash
complete -f -X '!*.bar' foo
```

Is it possible to do this in fish?

Answer (score 4):

Completing based on file extension is an attractive nuisance. You *think* you want it, but most of the time it is wrong. Most programs that *typically* use files with a specific extension will also happily work with others, and if they don't that's a weird restriction that could just as well be removed.

And if you restrict your completions to a specific extension and then need files without that's awkward to use.

Fish ships a helper function called `__fish_complete_suffix` that instead *sorts* the wanted extensions first. You would use it like this:

```
complete -c patch -s i -l input -x -k -a "(__fish_complete_suffix .patch .diff)"
```

This tells fish to complete the command `patch` with a `-i` or `--input` option which requires an argument but not via fish's builtin file completion (that's the `-x` flag), and keeps whatever order the completions were generated in (`-k`/`--keep-order`). To generate the completions, it runs `__fish_complete_suffix .patch .diff`, which sorts .patch and .diff files first.

You could adapt this to your command with:

```
complete -c foo -x -k -a "( __fish_complete_suffix .bar)"
```

---

If you really are sure that your command *needs* the file to be called ".bar", you can also generate this yourself with something like

```
complete -c foo -f -a '(complete -C"\'\' $(commandline -ct)" | string match -re "(?:/|.bar)\$")'
```

This tells fish to disable the builtin file completions (`-f`), and then matches files (by running the file completions by hand by asking it to complete the command `''`) ending in ".bar" or "/", so you get directories that might contain ".bar" files. You could also try to match .bar files everywhere, but that's prohibitively expensive typically - imagine if you try to run this in the filesystem root ($PWD of "/").

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! In my case, I'm adding tab completions for a function I wrote with a switch statement based on file extension, so there really are no other valid file extensions. It would be helpful if this was a feature built into fish, but I understand your point about not wanting this most of the time.